# How to successfully make working the IN_DELETE event?

Tags: c, linux, inotify

In this code, I am trying to make the IN_DELETE event working. Although IN_CREATE and IN_DELETE events are same as IN_DELETE but when I delete a file or a directory, the terminal show me nothing. Is there something with this code? Please help to improve this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/inotify.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
    
typedef struct{
    int fd, watchFd;
    char buffer[100];
} monitoring;
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    monitoring monitor;
    monitor.fd = inotify_init();
    monitor.buffer[sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1];
    struct inotify_event *evp;
    
    if(monitor.fd<0){
        perror("inotify_init not initialized: ");
        return -1;
    }
    
    monitor.watchFd = inotify_add_watch(monitor.fd, "/Projects/Project1", IN_CREATE|IN_MODIFY|IN_DELETE);

    while(1){
        read(monitor.fd, monitor.buffer, sizeof(monitor.buffer));
        evp = (struct inotify_event*)monitor.buffer;
        if(evp->len > 0){
            if(evp->mask & IN_CREATE){
                if(evp->mask & IN_ISDIR){
                    printf("Directory created: * %s\n", evp->name);
                }
                else{
                    printf("File created: * %s\n", evp->name);  
                }
            }
            if(evp->mask & IN_MODIFY){
                if(evp->mask & IN_ISDIR){
                    printf("Directory modified: ");
                }
                else{
                    printf("File modified: ");  
                }
            }
            if(evp->mask & IN_DELETE){
                if(evp->mask & IN_ISDIR){
                    printf("Directory deleted: * %s\n", evp->name);
                }
                else{
                    printf("File deleted: * %s\n", evp->name);  
                }
            }
        }
    }
    inotify_rm_watch(monitor.fd, monitor.watchFd);
    close(monitor.fd);
    
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: What is `monitor.buffer[sizeof(struct inotify_event) + NAME_MAX + 1];` supposed to do? You can't change the size of an array.

Comment: You probably should put that in the structure declaration.

Comment: `monitor.buffer` can contain multiple events. You're only showing the first one. You need to loop through all the events in the buffer. See the example [here](https://linuxhint.com/inotify_api_c_language/)

Comment: @Barmar I have another problem also which I am not understanding. What ``evp = (struct inotify_event*)monitor.buffer;`` does?

Comment: It's a normal type cast. It allows you to access the contents of the buffer as an `inotify_event` structure.